# Nexus 4: Stuck on boot animation for baseband version != 2.0.1700.48 and android version > 4.3

Tags: nexus-4, boot, boot-loop, radio-firmware

The symptoms I'm seeing seem to be common, with many suggested solutions, none of which I've found to solve my case.

I'm not sure to what extend it is related, but it happened after the screen was replaced. With the screen damaged and no touch input was registered, it was still booting and running CM11 fine. After replacing the screen, everything other than actually booting up the OS works. I can enter in ClockworkMod Recovery, access shell through `adb`, format the system (`/system`, `/data`, `/boot`, `/sdcard`, etc), flashing recovery, flashing the bootloader, flashing the radio, replacing the system with stock android.

I have tried erasing everything possible, flashing to Android Stock `4.4.4 (KTU84P)`, `4.4.2 (KOT49H)` w/corresponding bootloader and baseband (radio) versions. I've also tried locking and unlocking the OEM, forcing a system wipe. With USB-cable connected to usb charger, computer, and not at all. The result is the same, stuck on boot animation.

This is a series of steps for what works... sort of. Its current state marked as `[WORKS]`, meaning it boots up fine, and if not `[FAILS]` (if nothing else is specified, it ends up stuck on boot animation).

---

**Through stock 4.2.2, and subsequent system upgrades.**

1. `[WORKS]` Flashing to Android Stock `4.2.2 (JDQ39)`. Phone boots up fine, no issues.
2. `[FAILS]` System upgrade to `4.3 (JWR66Y)` OK. Note that baseband (radio) version is now `M9615A-CEFWMAZM-2.0.1700.84`.
3. `[WORKS]` Overriding radio version to `2.0.1700.48`, the one that came with `4.2.2 (JDQ39)` stock image.
            It now boots into 4.3 without issues.
4. `[FAILS]` Error screen after booting to perform system upgrade to `4.4` (possibly due to wrong baseband version). Reboots OK into `4.3`. No longer reports a possible system upgrade (checked 4 times, rebooted twice).

---

**Similar as above, but through `fastboot` and stock 4.3:**

1. `[FAILS]` Clean reset, flashing to Android Stock `4.3 (JWR66Y)` w/corresp bootloader and baseband.
2. `[WORKS]` Flashing baseband to `2.0.1700.48`

---

**Through stock 4.4**

1. `[FAILS]` Clean reset, flashing to Android Stock `4.4 (KRT16S)`  w/corresp bootloader and baseband.
2. `[FAILS]` Flashing baseband to `2.0.1700.48`

---

**Through stock 4.4.3**

1. `[FAILS]` Clean reset, flashing to Android Stock `4.4.3 (KTU84L)`
2. `[FAILS]` Flashing baseband to `2.0.1700.48`

---

**Through stock 4.4.4**

1. `[FAILS]` Clean reset, flashing to Android Stock `4.4.4 (KTU84P)`
2. `[FAILS]` Flashing baseband to `2.0.1700.48` (from 4.2.2)

---

I don't know what else to try, or how to understand this further.
The output of `/proc/last_kmsg` isn't very informative to me, but I've uploaded one such [here](http://pastebin.com/3Z112zp5).

***edit:*** Mostly groundless speculation, but it could maybe have something to do with drivers communicating with the battery and reading the battery level. Every time it has worked on 4.2.2 and 4.3 (with baseband from 4.2.2), it has (on the first boot up) reported battery level as 1%, even though it is much more charged than that. It continues to charge, and the percentage slowly increased to 5%, whereupon I rebooted it. After the reboot, it shows the battery level at 53%.